# Warning: Provided 'plot_folder' doesn't exist

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the robyn_outputs() function in R to export some plots and files to a specific folder using the plot_folder argument. However, I keep getting a warning message that says "Provided 'plot_folder' doesn't exist". I've checked that the folder exists and that the name is spelled correctly, but the warning persists. What could be causing this issue?

```
robyn_directory <- "C:/Users/HP/OneDrive/Documents/robyn_plots"

OutputCollect <- robyn_outputs(
  InputCollect, OutputModels,
  pareto_fronts = 5,
  csv_out = "pareto",
  clusters = TRUE,
  export = create_files,
  plot_folder = robyn_directory,
  plot_pareto = create_files
)

print(OutputCollect)
```

**Expected outcome:** The function should export the plots and files to the specified folder without any warning messages.

**Actual outcome:** The function returns a warning message that says "Provided 'plot_folder' doesn't exist", even though the folder exists and is spelled correctly.

Attempts to solve the issue:

I've checked that the folder exists and is spelled correctly.
I've tried running R with administrator privileges.
I've tried using an absolute path for the plot_folder argument.
None of these solutions have worked so far.

Comment: Seems like this may be a known issue? Which version of the `Robyn` package are you using? See: https://github.com/facebookexperimental/Robyn/issues/318